# Triggers adding rows

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers

I'm trying to create triggers that add rows in a tab when another tab is updated.

I would like to know if my things are correct. I use Oracle and Java.

```
statmnt.executeQuery("CREATE TABLE operations
                            ( operation_id INTEGER, 
                              account_id INTEGER, 
                              amount FLOAT DOUBLE PRECISION, 
                               DATE NOT NULL");

 statmnt.executeQuery("CREATE TABLE accounts 
                       ( account_id INTEGER, 
                          name VARCHAR2 (45 CHAR) NOT NULL, 
                         balance FLOAT DOUBLE PRECISION)"); 

 statmnt.executeQuery("ALTER TABLE accounts 
                      ADD CONSTRAINT accounts_PK PRIMARY KEY 
                      ( accounts_id )");

statmnt.executeQuery("ALTER TABLE operations 
                      ADD CONSTRAINT accountID FOREIGN KEY 
                   ( operation_accountID "+ "REFERENCES accounts 
                   ( account_id ) ON");  

statmnt.executeQuery("CREATE TRIGGER addingOrder 
                      BEFORE UPDATE ON accounts 
                       BEGIN"
                     + "INSERT INTO operations
                         (operation_id, account_id, amount, date) "
                     + "VALUES (operationID.nextval, :OLD.account_id,
                      :NEW.accounts - :OLD.account, GETDATE()) END;");
```

Comment: What happens when you try to do this? It's wrong, but what errors do you get first?

Comment: in oracle trigger there should be `for each row` and some more syntax errors r there..tell exactly what errror u r getting

Comment: Why don't you execute your DDL in SQLPLUS or SQL Developer and get some feedback from the database itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, things are not correct. You have one or two problems, which as Rene said would be more obvious if you ran these statements from a normal client/IDE instead of from your own application. Some of the more obvious issues:

First create statement:

- You don't have a closing parenthesis
- `FLOAT DOUBLE PRECISION` isn't a valid data type; it's either `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE PRECISION`, not both (but be really sure you don't just want `NUMBER`)
- you haven't supplied an identifier for your `DATE` column; from the trigger you seem to think that is the column name, but if so you don't have a data type, and it isn't a valid name because it's a keyword

Second create statement:

- `FLOAT DOUBLE PRECISION` again

First alter statement:

- You don't have a column called `accounts_id`; it's `account_id`

Second alter statement:

- You're missing a closing parenthesis before `REFERENCES`
- You don't have a column called `operation_accountID`
- You have `ON` trailing at the end, not sure what that is supposed to be doing; maybe you meant `ENABLE`?

Trigger statement:

- you're missing whitespace where you are concatenating strings, between `BEGIN` and `INSERT`
- you're using `date` as an identifier (see earlier comment on the table creation)
- you have to have a `for each row` trigger to access the NEW and OLD pseudorows
- you're referencing pseudorow columns that don't exist in the table
- `GETDATE()` isn't an Oracle function, you hopefully mean `SYSDATE`
- you don't have a semicolon after the insert statement

And probably some other things I missed...

Comment: omg thx a lot. It was a bit messy, sry. However, i understood how "for each row" works ! :) if i run this with SQLPlus, it will just tell me that it compiles with errors, which doesn't help much ^^'

Comment: @Csi - if you see that, do `show errors` to see the details. You can also query the `user_errors` view.